# cannot import name 'dataset' from 'netCDF4' (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.7, netcdf

I'm trying to read a `netcdf` file but it always shows the `ImportError: cannot import name 'dataset' from 'netCDF4'`.

I have installed the `netcdf4` using python using `conda install netcdf4` and its have been successfully installed. At the same time I have updated my `numpy` for it to match my current version of `netcdf4`. I also have tried installing `pip install netcdf4` on the command prompt.

```py
from netCDF4 import dataset
f = dataset('3B43.20170101.7.HDF')

print (Jan01.NETCDF4_CLASSIC)
```

I expected that it could open the file (`netcdf`). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
f = Dataset('3B43.20170101.7.HDF')
```

Comment: Hello! It worked but I got this result:

netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__()
netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'3B43.20170101.7.HDF' and the file is in the same folder with the one i'm making program with.

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version of netcdf?